# Second cohomology group $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})$ of a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, closed-form

I was reading proposition 3.13 in http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/lecnotes/repq.pdf in which they prove that $H^2(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{R})=0$ if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple. Let $\omega\in\wedge^2\mathfrak{g}^*$ be closed. Why does there exist a linear map $\phi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\omega(X,Y)=\kappa(X,\phi(Y))$ where $\kappa$ is the Killing form. I don't see where it comes from. Is it due to the nondegeneracy of the Killing form?

Comment: Yes, it follows from the nondegeneracy of the Killing form. This will probably become clearer if you write out the defining equation in terms of matrix representations w.r.t. some arbitrary basis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the claim follows from the nondegeneracy of the Killing form:

Fix any basis of $\mathfrak{g}$; then, we can rephrase the condition as the existence of a matrix $[\phi]$ such that $$[\omega] = [\kappa] [\phi] ,$$ where $[\omega]$ and $[\kappa]$ are respectively the matrix representations of $\omega, \kappa$ with respect to the basis. Since $\kappa$ is nondegenerate, so is $[\kappa]$, and we may rearrange to find an explicit expression for $\phi$.

Comment: (In particular, this question is more about linear algebra than, e.g., computing cohomology groups.)

Comment: That is, $[\phi]=[\kappa]^{-1}[\omega]$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you prefer index notation (which requires no choice of basis), you can write this $\phi^a{}_b = (\kappa^{-1})^{ac} \omega_{cb}$, where $\kappa^{-1}$ is the inverse metric $\kappa$ determines on $\mathfrak g^*$.